# expressValidator is not a function even it specifies middleware must be function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
//route.js
> const {body} = require('express-validator');
var validate=(method) =>{
    switch(method){
        case 'userRegistered':{
            return [
                body('username','Username doesnot exists').exists(),
                body('email','Invalid Email').exists().isEmail(),
                body('name','Invalid Email').optional(),
                body('password','password must be atleast 8 characters').exists().isLength({min:8,max:15}),
                body('Image','please upload your Image').exists(),

            ]
        }
    }
}
//route Handler
> router.post('/register-user',uploads.single('Image'),validate('userRegistered'),async(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.file);

const errors = validationResult(req)
if(!errors.isEmpty){
    res.status(422).json({errors:errors.array() });
}
await userRegistered(req.body,req.file.path,"client",res);
});
//app.js
> const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(expressValidator());
```

// I use express validation as middleware in my REST API but got an error of
// app.use(expressValidator());
^

TypeError: expressValidator is not a function

Comment: This looks like you simply haven't read [the instructions](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) which tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You require the `check` and `validationResult` objects from the package

pass an array of `check()` calls as the second argument of the post() call. Every check() call accepts the parameter name as argument. Then we call `validationResult()` to verify there were no validation errors. If there are any, tell them to the client

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/register-user', [
  check('name').isLength({ min: 3 }),
  check('email').isEmail(),
],async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
  }
  //do something
})
```